# Enabling helm interferes with R/ESS

Tags: init-file, helm, ess, r

I have helm enabled in an Org file that `init.el` calls. The code looks like the following:

```
(use-package helm
     :config (require 'helm-config))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") #'helm-M-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r b") #'helm-filtered-bookmarks)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") #'helm-find-files)
(helm-mode 1)
```

Without this code, if I open up an R script and, let's call it `foo.R`, that contains just:

```
2 + 2
```

And I navigate to the line with `2 + 2` on it and type `C-<return>`, R is launched.

However, if the helm code is enabled, then I get this message in `wrong-type-argument window-live-p nil message` and R is not launched. Looking at `*Backtrace*` I see the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Running helm command outside of context")
  signal(error ("Running helm command outside of context"))
  error("Running helm command outside of context")
  helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit()
  funcall-interactively(helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit)
  call-interactively(helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit)
```

However, if I have an R terminal open via, `M-x R`, then I can use `C-<return>` and it will send code to R. However, this is not how I typically work and I'm wondering why enabling helm interfered with  this.

EDIT:
In the case where `C-<return>` isn't working, when I run `C-h k C-<return>`, I get the following:

```
C-<return> runs the command ess-eval-region-or-line-visibly-and-step,
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘ess-inf.el’.

It is bound to C-<return>, <menu-bar> <ess> <Eval region | line>,
<menu-bar> <ess> <ESS Eval> <Eval region | line & step>.

(ess-eval-region-or-line-visibly-and-step)

Evaluate region if active, otherwise the current line and step.
Evaluation is done visibly.

Note that when inside a package and namespaced evaluation is in
place (see ‘ess-r-set-evaluation-env’) evaluation of multiline
input will fail.

[back]
```

Comment: In the bad situation, what is `C-<return>` bound to?  Do `C-h k C-<return>` to find out and report back.

Comment: The issue is with `read-directory-name` in `ess-prompt-for-directory`. I'm not sure how to fix the error, but to bypass it you could set `ess-ask-for-ess-directory` to nil, or start R before pressing `C-<return>`.

Comment: @jagrg, that solved it. Should I open a bug report with helm or ESS?

Comment: I don't know. I'd start with Helm and move on from there.